# Need help wiring and design/layout questions

Tags: wiring, aluminum-wiring

I am installing a 60 amp outdoor sub-panel 600+ feet away from the 200 amp main service panel.  Here is what I am doing based on my requirements:

1. Run a 2-2-2-4 Aluminum underground feeder to this 60 AMP panel and breaking this distance with two Quazite (Underground junction) boxes.

   - I have 24 light post, 12 on each side of the driveway, and 6 outlets, 3 on each side of the driveway. The Quazite boxes will help to run wires to each light and electrical outlets.
2. I will have 3 120V pumps (8 amps each), Gate opener, Lights and outlets hooked to this sub panel.

My questions:

1. Is the 2-2-2-4 Aluminum underground feeder good enough for the distance of 600 feet?
2. Should I run one straight feeder or break it in the Quazite boxes?

Comment: Someone else will be along with their opinion on the wire gauge.  Unless required by your local code, the boxes may not be required but may be a "nice to have" in the event you ever need to service or upgrade the wiring.  In that light, you might also consider using conduit vs. direct burial wire.  That will allow you to upgrade the wires in the future.  Also the boxes will help with pulling the wire.

Comment: Since electrical codes vary, where in the world are you? Since there will presumably be wire connections on those Quazite boxes, the covers for them will remain accessible, right? According to NEC, you can't bury a box with a splice and not provide a method for accessing it for repairs.

Comment: Yes.  I am planning on a 2 inch conduit ans boxed will be at grade level not buried.  I checked the local Code (NJ) waterproof wire nuts are acceptable for connections.

Comment: Thank you Both.   Now i need confirm the wire size/gauge.

Comment: How much power actually needed for the 24 lights? Big difference between 2 Amps each for big floodlights vs. a small fraction of that for LEDs lighting a small area. Total usage at one time determines the amount of power needed and from that how much any voltage drop issue will be. If you have 60 A (x240) but most of the time only use a small fraction (so far only known is 24A x 120 for the pumps) then it is different from "maxing out".

Comment: Yeah... I would think that the heavy _feeder_ wire needs to go _feed_ from the main panel to the subpanel. Then you run a circuit from the subpanel back to the lights and outlets. You may consider having each side of the driveway on its own breaker so if one side goes out, you've still got power on the other side - with 12 lights, I'd imagine this isn't a 30' driveway, so 1/2 lighting is better than none, and you can run an extension cord across the driveway for power to fix things on the other side as needed.

Comment: Thank you.  Last year when I had my driveway done I had laid 4" schedule 40 running under /across my driveway so wiring outlets on both side shouldn't be a problem.  I agree with you idea on having 2 separate breakers for each side, but I need to have the light switches in foyer inside the house.  So would I have to run a separate circuit foe the lighting?

Comment: Are you planning to tap the #2 Al wire at each Quazite box? If so, how will you provide circuit breaker protection to the outlets? How will the lights be controlled? Is it possible to source 240V versions of those lights?

Comment: Quazite boxes are so I can bring back the circuits (Outlets, Gate opener, pumps)from the sub panel.  Now I am considering running a separate circuit from the main panel as I would need the switch inside the house.  Response to FreeMan:  Each lamp post has 180 Watts of light which I believe equates to approx 1.5 AMPs, I can put the lights on a separate 40 AMP breaker?